# Injection of autowired dependencies failed in springboot application

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I want to start my Spring Boot application with an embedded Tomcat and create the database at runtime.

I wrote the following application.properties file:

```
server.port=1111
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring-boot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

This is my main class:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("ma.mahmoud.springboot")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

For the DAO I use Spring Data, so I created the following interface:

```java
public interface PlaceRepository extends CrudRepository<Place, Long> {

Place findByShortName(String shortName);
}
```

This is the interface I wrote for my service:

```java
public interface PlaceService {
    Place getPlaceByShortName(String shortName);
}
```

And the implementation of this service is like this:

```java
@Service
public class PlaceServiceImpl implements PlaceService {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceRepository placeRepository;


    public Place getPlaceByShortName(String shortName) {
        return placeRepository.findByShortName(shortName);
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS 
}
```

Initially, my application was throwing the following error on startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'placeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ma.mahmoud.springboot.repository.PlaceRepository ma.mahmoud.springboot.service.impl.PlaceServiceImpl.placeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ma.mahmoud.springboot.repository.PlaceRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**EDIT**

However, after replacing the annotations on my main class by `@SpringBootApplication` and by correcting the `spring.jpa.database-platform` to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry;)V from class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService
```

I'm using the following pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm not using any XML configuration for Spring since I use annotations. Did I forget something? Or do I need another annotation to make it work?

Comment: Is `PlaceRepository` annotated as repository?

Comment: I try it but it's not working

Comment: It should work if the interface is in package `ma.mahmoud.springboot` and the annotation @Repository is added

Comment: the class PlaceRepository is in this package : ma.mahmoud.springboot.repository , I add the @Repository annotation but nothing changed

Comment: try to add `@SpringBootApplication` on your Application  class

Comment: You have an error in your configuration file : you're using PostgreSQLDialect with MySQL database. Not sure if it causes your problem but you might have a previous error telling you that he can not create your repository.

Comment: @MatthieuSaleta I edit my my file but the persiste

Comment: @Mahmoud can you verify that there are no other errors in the log?

Comment: @Jens the SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan ; So I already have them in my class

Comment: @Mahmoud did you try to replace those annotations with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: @g00glen00b yes try it, but I get annother error , I think it's linked to the version of springboot

Comment: Spring Boot 1.4 requires Spring 4.3 (as mentioned on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes). If you need to use Spring 4.2, use an older Spring Boot version.

Comment: I add the project in git lab, if you want to see all apps, check this link https://gitlab.com/m.lotfi/spring-boot/tree/master

Comment: So does it work with Spring 4.3?

Comment: @dunni , Yes, but i have the first error: `Error creating bean with name 'placeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'placeService'`

Answer (score 2):

The code looks correct, however, your dialect is not. You originally had set the `PostgreSQLDialect` for a MySQL database, but now you replaced it by `MYSQLDialect` which is not a valid dialect.

So you should probably use:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Or if you're using MySQL < 5.x you should use:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

The "y" in MySQL should be **lowercase** in both cases. A complete list of all the dialects can be found in the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html). However, the dialect isn't mandatory in most cases, so you can try to remove the `spring.jpa.database-platform` property as well.

To answer your edited question, you have an inconsistency between your Spring- and Spring boot version. If you don't have any reason to change the Spring version (or even the Hibernate version), you should probably not do it, you should remove the following lines from your **pom.xml**:

```
<hibernate.version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate.version>
<spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Comment: thunks for your share, but the is not the probleme

Comment: @Mahmoud make sure to update the code in your question to contain your current code and show us the error when you use `@SpringBootApplication`. If you're getting some error due to incorrect versions, it might be the cause. Right now, this code **should** work.

Comment: i Edited my question

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot 1.4 requires a minimum of Spring 4.3, as mentioned on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes:

> Spring Boot 1.4 builds on and requires Spring Framework 4.3.

So you can either downgrade to Spring Boot 1.3.x or use Spring 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories("package")` on top of your `Application` class.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary because `@EnableAutoConfiguration` will add `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: I personally use all `@ComponentScan("package")`, 
`@EntityScan("pckg")`,
`@EnableJpaRepositories("pckg")`, 
`@SpringBootApplication` because i have a multi modular project, without specifying everything, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the dialect. I have a similar application, and following is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/[db_name]
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update[or "create-drop" if you want the tables created] 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Try this

Answer (score -2):

1.Add **anyone of @Component** annotation into the **Impelmentation** class of PlaceRepository.

2.Make sure whether the package PlaceRepository & its implementation are added into **@ComponentScan**

Comment: I don't have implementation for PlaceRepository, I use SpringData and all methods do CRUD thats exist in the CrudRepository.

Comment: @downvoters, please leave comment. Hi Mahmoud,Without Implementation class how can you create bean for that interface? Your attempt in equivalent to create new instance for an interface using new operator, which not possible without implementation class/anoymous class for that interface.

Comment: He uses Spring Data JPA, so that will take care of the bean creation. If you don't know that framework, please read yourself before giving false answers. Downvotes are justified.

Comment: @dunni, Thanks for the explanation & educating. I will learn from this mistake.